# First Log in RedirectToAction MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

I need to Redirect to specific page a user on his or her first log in after registration. I put the following in web.config:

```
<profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <add name="isNewUser" type="System.Boolean"/>
      </properties>
    </profile>
```

Then in Controller I am writing the following:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // This doen't count login failures towards lockout only two factor authentication
            // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Email, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, model.RememberMe);
                    var profile = ProfileBase.Create(model.Email);
                    var FirstTime = profile.GetPropertyValue("isNewUser");
                    var chk = FirstTime;
                    if (chk.Equals(true))
                        return RedirectToAction("FirstUser", "Index");
                    else if (chk.Equals(false))
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

                    else
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

But it is not redirecting to FirstUser page.

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `FirstTime`? You did add a name and a type in web.config, but not a value. Default bool = false.

Comment: But my problem is sql profiler tables are not functioning. There are ASPNET tables of Identity. And I installed schemas for stored procedures and those tables are not capturing data

Comment: That seems like another problem, I think you should ask a new question.